# How to get Attribute Text depending on storeId in magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products, store-id

I want to get attributeText of product depending on  what storeId is passed.

Comment: `$attribute->getStoreLabel()`  for current store attribute label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get AttributeText by passing storeId from product collection:

```
$stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
foreach ($stores as $key => $store) {
    $store_id          = $store->getId();
    $productCollection = $this->getProductCollection($store_id);
    foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
        $productdetails    = $_product->getData();
        $_conditionDefault = $_product->getResource()
                                      ->getAttribute('condition')
                                      ->setStoreId($store_id)
                                      ->getFrontend()
                                      ->getValue($_product);
        echo $_conditionDefault;
    }
}

protected function getProductCollection($store_id)
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addStoreFilter($store_id)
        ->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status',
            array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        );

    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this..

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productId = 2; //Product ID
    $storeId = 1 //Store ID
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
    $attributeValue = $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'attribute_code',$storeId); //change attribute_code
    var_dump($attributeValue);
?>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: won't this return the id of an option instead of the label?

Comment: No @Marius, It will return value of attribute not ID. :)

Comment: How to get item attribute values based on store-level on order summary section at checkout Magento 2

Comment: The question asked for the attributeText, not the raw value.

Comment: It's will return default store value if specific store does not have value for that field.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested, but this might work:

Let's say `$product` is the product instance.
and `$code` is the attribute code for which you need the label.
and `$storeId` the id of the store you need.

```
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($code);
$attribute->setStoreId($storeId);
$text = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($product->getData($code));
```

Comment: How to get item attribute values based on store-level on order summary section at checkout Magento 2

Comment: This answer is exactly what worked for me instead of using another object manager.